# Data security around _id and _rev in CouchDB

Tags: architecture, nosql, couchdb

This is almost certainly a stupid question, but I want to be safe and so I think its always worth double-checking.

As long as I have proper authentication (in my case cookie-based on a 1 database to 1 user basis), then is there any risk in exposing full document contents (i.e. including `_id` and `_rev`) in every single GET/PUT relating that document?

By this I mean, is there any conceivable way that providing the *whole* document, rather than just it's core data could result in updates being more easily tampered with?

The only way around exposing the `_rev` to the client, would be to do a `HEAD` request [server-side] before each `PUT` in order to get the latest revision number - which seems like madness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that providing the *whole* document could result in updates being more easily tampered with.

If you are using per-database security, then you have a perfect foundation.

The primary policy that enforces read security is the `_security` object. The primary policy that enforces write security is the `validate_doc_update` function.

So I think the _id and _rev will not factor into a security assessment of your application.